# SQL Server: Merge two rows of same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm trying to merge the rows from a table in below manner.

The table contains logs about the Request, Response, RequestTime and ResponseTime made to an API.

[Please find the attached image here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qn8Lh.jpg)

Both Request and Response columns in the desired output are both populated from Message column of base table.

Similarly, the RequestTime and ResponseTime columns in the desired output are both populated from Date column of base table.

I have tried the below code and it is getting me desired output but I don't think this is the right way to do it.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetPackageRequestResponseDetails]
    @PACKAGEID VARCHAR(20)  
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @ApiLogDump TABLE
    (
        Date DATETIME,
        Thread VARCHAR(255),
        Logger VARCHAR(255),
        Message VARCHAR(4000)
    )

    INSERT INTO @ApiLogDump
    (
        Date,
        Thread,
        Logger,
        Message
    )
    SELECT
        Date,
        Thread,
        Logger,
        Message
    FROM APILog
    WHERE Logger LIKE '%GetPackageDetails%'
    AND Message LIKE '%'+@PACKAGEID+'%'

    DECLARE  @ApiLogMerge TABLE
    (
        Thread VARCHAR(255),
        Request VARCHAR(4000),
        Response VARCHAR(4000),
        RequestTime DATETIME,
        ResponseTime DATETIME
    )

    INSERT INTO @ApiLogMerge
    (   
        Thread,
        Request,
        Response,
        RequestTime,
        ResponseTime
    )
    SELECT 
        Thread,
        Message,
        Null,
        Date,
        Null
    FROM @ApiLogDump
    WHERE Message LIKE '%Request:'+@PACKAGEID+'%'


    UPDATE @ApiLogMerge
        SET Response = A.Message,
            ResponseTime = A.Date
    FROM @ApiLogMerge AP JOIN @ApiLogDump A
       ON AP.Thread = A.Thread
    WHERE Message LIKE '%Response:{"PackageID":"'+@PACKAGEID+'"%'

    SELECT * FROM @ApiLogMerge ORDER BY RequestTime DESC

END
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is your 1 clear specific non-duplicate question? "Any help" is not a valid question. "I don't think this is the right way" is not helpful or a question. "in below manner" & "populated from" are vague. PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output; tags & versions; clear specification & explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below logic using GROUP BY and other conditions.

```
SELECT Thread,
MAX(CASE WHEN LEFT(Message,7) = 'Request' THEN Message ELSE NULL END) Request,
MAX(CASE WHEN LEFT(Message,8) = 'Response' THEN Message ELSE NULL END) Response,
MAX(CASE WHEN LEFT(Message,7) = 'Request' THEN Date ELSE NULL END) RequestTime,
MAX(CASE WHEN LEFT(Message,8) = 'Response' THEN Date ELSE NULL END) ResponseTime
FROM BaseTable
GROUP BY Thread
```